# Unexpected Token error while using Inquirer.js module in Node JS

Tags: node.js, npm, inquirer

I am using Inquirer.JS in my Node project. It returns an unexpected token error. My code is:

```
import inquirer from 'inquirer';

inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
        message: "Type in your URL",
        name: "URL",
    },
    ])
  .then((answers) => {
    console.log(answers);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.isTtyError) {
      // Prompt couldn't be rendered in the current environment
    } else {
      // Something else went wrong
    }
  });
```

Error is:

```
file:///C:/Users/LINU/Desktop/StudyNotes/qr-code-generator/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/expand.js:100
    input ||= this.rawDefault;
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Use a version of Node that Inquirer supports (or an older version of Inquirer that supports your version of Node, but really you should be past v14 by now)? https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

install this version

```
npm install --save inquirer@^8.0.0
```

and use

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
```